# What is the difference between GDI and GDI+?

Tags: gdi+, gdi

Are there any differences between those two libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [the wikipedia article on GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface):

> With the introduction of Windows XP, GDI was deprecated in favor of its successor, the C++ based GDI+ subsystem. **GDI+ adds anti-aliased 2D graphics, floating point coordinates, gradient shading, more complex path management, intrinsic support for modern graphics-file formats like JPEG and PNG, and support for composition of affine transformations in the 2D view pipeline**.

Comment: Actually [MSDN does not mention GDI to be deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so I'd suggest GDI can be (at the moment) safely used for C procedural usage, while GDI+ stands for C++ OO usage.

Answer (score 9):

GDI is not object oriented and provide hardware abstraction for win32 plateform. It's written in C

GDI+ is object oriented, and it's main purpose is to provide C++ classes to simplify and extend in some ways GDI usage.

GDI+ also target .NET , as System.Drawing is integrating it

Answer (score 7):

GDI+ is an improvement on GDI.  It contains features not readily available in GDI such as gradient brushes, alpha blending, and more image format support.

You can see what other differences are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Windows_XP):

> GDI+ adds anti-aliased 2D graphics, floating point coordinates, gradient shading, more complex path management, intrinsic support for modern graphics-file formats like JPEG and PNG, and support for composition of affine transformations in the 2D view pipeline. GDI+ uses ARGB values to represent color.